# subset data frame on vector sequence

Tags: r

I have the data frame `df` and I want to subset `df` based on a number sequence within a categorical.

```
 x  <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13)
 x2 <- x+77 
 df <- data.frame(x=c(x,x2),y= c(rep("A",9),rep("B",9)))

 df
    x y
1   1 A
2   2 A
3   3 A
4   4 A
5   5 A
6   7 A
7   9 A
8  11 A
9  13 A
10 78 B
11 79 B
12 80 B
13 81 B
14 82 B
15 84 B
16 86 B
17 88 B
18 90 B
```

I want only the rows where `x` increments by 1 and not the rows where `x` increases by two: e.g.

```
    x y
1   1 A
2   2 A
3   3 A
4   4 A
5   5 A
10 78 B
11 79 B
12 80 B
13 81 B
14 82 B
```

I figured I have to do some dort of subtraction between elements and check if the difference is `>1` and combine this with a `ddply` but this seems cumbersome. Is there a sort of `sequence` function I am missing?

Comment: What would you want to return in the case of a 19th row of `91 B`?

Comment: @BenBarnes thank you for thinking very general, however in my instance this should never happen.

Comment: `?diff` would be a good starting point (`diff(df$x)`, for example), but you would need to do some adjustment to get it to work correctly. By the way, the values for `x` and `x2` is not in your question.

Comment: @mrdwab thanks corrected, I'll check `diff` just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using diff

```
df[which(c(1,diff(df$x))==1),]
```

Comment: thank you very much this doesnt grab `78 B` but when I split apply this will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your example seems to behave well and can be nicely handled by @agstudy's answer. Should your data act up one day, though...

```
myfun <- function(d, whichDiff = 1) {
  # d is the data.frame you'd like to subset, containing the variable 'x'
  # whichDiff is the difference between values of x you're looking for

  theWh <- which(!as.logical(diff(d$x) - whichDiff))
  # Take the diff of x, subtract whichDiff to get the desired values equal to 0
  # Coerce this to a logical vector and take the inverse (!)
  # which() gets the indexes that are TRUE.

  # allWh <- sapply(theWh, "+", 1)
  # Since the desired rows may be disjoint, use sapply to get each index + 1
  # Seriously? sapply to add 1 to a numeric vector? Not even on a Friday.
  allWh <- theWh + 1

  return(d[sort(unique(c(theWh, allWh))), ])
}

> library(plyr)
> 
> ddply(df, .(y), myfun)
    x y
1   1 A
2   2 A
3   3 A
4   4 A
5   5 A
6  78 B
7  79 B
8  80 B
9  81 B
10 82 B
```